# How can i get data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, ios, web-services

I have a couple of easy problems.

First I am trying to get names from database where `surname='lion'`.  I wrote php a file but it didn't work:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","yata_ali","password");

if (!$con){
   die('error: ' . mysql_error());    
}

mysql_select_db("yatanada_iBess", $con);

$degisken = mysql_query("select name from people where  surname LIKE '%lion%'");

if(mysql_query){
   return "$degisken";
}  

 mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I wrote this code and tried to use $degisken in my xcode project. But it didn't work.
shortly i am trying to use the names whichs surname =lion in my ios project and i know i should use url.but i couldn find the code part that return name what shall i write at the end of php code ? return or something else to use in xcode. 
how can i send response in php? i wonder that. what shall i write "return $name" or something else. i know call url. but i dont know whats the full php code that i shall use

Comment: Your second question should be a) a separate post and b) should explain what you're trying to accomplish and what steps you've taken so far to accomplish these steps.

Comment: The OP should consider changing his database password, as it seems, username, password, dbname are listed here and the domain name is visible in his profile.

Comment: I notice you have edited out your password in the question. I hope you will change your actual password. Users here can still see the original post, so your database may be vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use PHP in an iOS project.  You'll need to write some objective-c to call a URL on a server which returns this data in some sort of format (xml? json?) and then have the iOS app parse the response.

Comment: how can i send response in php? i wonder that. what shall i write "return $name" or something else. i know call url. but i dont know whats the full php code that i shall use.

Comment: You need to a) set up a web server that runs PHP that can talk to the machine mysql is running on. b) write a script that generates JSON from a data set returned by mysql. c) write an iOS app, in objective-c, that calls that URL that returns the JSON (from steps a and b) and then parses the response and uses it.  If you'd like help with any of these steps, please post a question about a specific issue you're having with something you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors, in your code, but the most serious are that

- (a) you are running an invalid test:

  if (mysql_query){ //YOU CANNOT DO THIS
- (b) You cannot `return "$degisken";` because `$degisken` is a MySQL
  resource, not a string.
- (c) You should not close your mysql
  connection after returning something. You don't necessarily need to
  close it at all, but if you're going to, close it after the query
  because anything after the `return` won't be evaluated (assuming the
  return is triggered).
- (d) If you're looking for cases where the surname='lion' then don't use wildcards in the MySQL query. `where surname LIKE '%lion%'` will match 'scalion','lioness','slioner', etc.

Your code should look something like this:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","yatanada_ali","sifre");
if (!$con) {
    die('error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("yatanada_iBess", $con);

$degisken = mysql_query("select name from people where surname LIKE '%lion%'") or die('Error: '. mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($degisken)){
   //your query could return lots of results, so you may want to loop through results:
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
       $name = $row['name'];
       //do something with the name... I'm going to echo it.
       echo  $name . "<br />";
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks code is succesfull. but i asked omething else. i need use $name in my xcode project. i know when i need add data in mysql i sholud use post or get but i dont know how can i use data in mysql table. so i think i need php code  like return $name. and i will call this code in my xcode project as url.

Comment: You can use `echo json_encode($name)` (if there is one name, or if you want to report an array of names you can create a variable `$names=array()` and in the while loop just `$names[]=$name`. Then, once the loop completes say `echo json_encode($names)`. If you're calling it as a URL, you'll need to have a webserver running as well, but just `echo`ing the encoded data is all you'll need to do. (`return` only returns data internally... it does not output to the browser/request agent)

Comment: Ok Ben. i have a quetion. i did what you told. and there is my code:<?php
// 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","yatan","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Baglanti saglanamadi: ' . mysql_error());
  }mysql_select_db("yatanada", $con);
  $degisken= mysql_query("select name from people where surname LIKE '%lion%'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($degisken))
  {
 
   echo  json_encode($row);
   
 }
  mysql_close($con);
?>

Comment: What's your question? You've gotten very close, but you should put all of your results into a multidimensional array and encode that (unless you have a parser that can understand multiple seperate JSON objects). I'm guessing, however, that you should just: `$multi_array = array();while($row = mysql_fetch_array($degisken)){$multi_array[] = $row;} echo json_encode($multi_arra);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand how to use the mysql_* functions in PHP. Take a look at the examples on this page for guidance: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$degisken= mysql_query("select name from people where surname='lion'");

if ($degisken){

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($degisken))
  {
     echo $row["name"] . "<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: i need use $name in my xcode project. i meaned  i need end of code.Ok i got data from table but how my url can use it? what shall i write return or somethng else? i think echo isnt enough